# is there a standard way to calculate number of days between two asctime() values

Tags: c++, date

like number of days between `Mon Jun 08 09:21:39 2020` and `Mon Jun 18 07:11:29 2020` is 10.
otherwise, I am thinking of creating a function to calculate difference by using `Jan=31`, `Feb=28`, ... and so on but that would be lengthy.
Is there a direct/better way to do the same.

Comment: Nope, there might be some custom third party libraries out there to do date math, but there's very little of that in the standard C++ library, and you'll have to do the job yourself.

Comment: Time/date calculations are notoiously tricky so someone will problably tell me this is wrong. But I would convert both times into 'seconds since the epoch' form, subtract one from another and then divide by the number of seconds in a day.

Comment: The safest way is to convert date to Julian Day Number. The difference between two JDN is the number of days. For formula to convert, you can look it up on the net. One example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

Comment: Do the times-of-day matter, and how? It needs to be clarified whether the required result is an integer or a fractional number of days, and whether locale DST must be accounted for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that shows one way to do it, by first converting the ASCII strings into `struct tm`'s, then converting the `struct tm`'s into `time_t`'s, and then calculating the difference (in seconds) between the two `time_t`'s and finally converting that into days:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int, char **)
{
    const char * tStr1 = "Mon Jun 08 09:21:39 2020";
    const char * tStr2 = "Mon Jun 18 07:11:29 2020";

    // convert ASCII strings to struct tm's --
    // you can skip this part of you already have
    // the struct tm's available (in addition to ASCII strings)

    struct tm tm1;
    if (strptime(tStr1, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", &tm1) == NULL)
    {
       printf("Couldn't parse tStr1=[%s]\n", tStr1);
       exit(10);
    }

    struct tm tm2;
    if (strptime(tStr2, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", &tm2) == NULL)
    {
       printf("Couldn't parse tStr2=[%s]\n", tStr2);
       exit(10);
    }

    // convert the struct tm's to time_t's
    const time_t t1 = mktime(&tm1);
    const time_t t2 = mktime(&tm2);

    // Calculate the difference between the two time_t's
    const time_t diff = difftime(t2, t1);

    // Convert seconds to days
    const double days = ((double)diff) / (60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0);

    printf("The difference between the two timestamps is %f days.\n", days);

    return 0;
}
```